# Double click event and Enter event in a same time in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent

I want to call event when I press Enter Key or Dubble click.
 I write this code for pressing Enter Key, But I don't know How can insert condition for dubble click.

```
onClickNode: function (node) {
      $(document).keyup(function (e) {
                            if (e.which == 13) {
                                $.ajax({
                                        url: '@Url.Action("EditNode", "Admin")',
                                        type: 'POST',
                                        data: { id: node.data.id,name:node.data.name},
                                        success: function (data) {
                                          if (data.Success) {
                                             // do something
                                                             }
                                             //do something
                                          });

                                                                  },
                                      });     
                                                 }
                                      });
                        }
```

Can you change this code with enter or dubble click press?

Comment: `$(document).on('dblclick keyup')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).on("keyup", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            commonMethod(node);
        }
    });

    $(document).on("dblclick", function (e) {
        commonMethod(node);
    });

    function commomMethod(node) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("EditNode", "Admin")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: node.data.id,
                name: node.data.name
            },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.Success) {
                    // do something
                }
                //do something
            }
        });
    }
```